# MongoDB Unwind array result manipulation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following MongoDB Query:

Which returns some rows of two collections, a ton which have the 362 netcode, then I "join" these two collections in a new array which contains the 2nd info, of those array I extract the "group".

```
     db.events.aggregate([

       { $match : { netcode : "N000362" } },

        {
          $lookup:
            {
              from: "nodes",
              localField: "name",
          foreignField: "name",
          as: "event_joined"


        }

   },


  { $unwind:  {path: "$event_joined"}},


  { $project : { name : 1, event : 1, "event_joined.group": 1 ,_id:0} },







])
```

And it returns me the following result (There are much more lines):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "name" : "GFS_3MSTAFE_RT01",
    "event" : "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation",
    "event_joined" : {
        "group" : "GFS-SUCURSALES"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "name" : "GFS_3MSTAFE_RT01",
    "event" : "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation",
    "event_joined" : {
        "group" : "GFS-SUCURSALES"
    }
}
```

what i want:

```
   /* 1 */
{
    "name" : "GFS_3MSTAFE_RT01",
    "event" : "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation",
    "group" : "GFS-SUCURSALES"

}

/* 2 */
{
    "name" : "GFS_3MSTAFE_RT01",
    "event" : "Proactive Interface Output Utilisation",  
    "group" : "GFS-SUCURSALES"

}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I tried with another unwind, and nope.

Comment: Try `{ $project : { name : 1, event : 1, group:"$event_joined.group", _id:0 } }`

Comment: Indeed yes, Thank you very much :D

Such an easy syntax should be in MongoDB doc, in the $project section... Pffff ...

I dont know how to flag this as an answer, but definitely is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [computed fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-computed-fields) to project the values from embedded doc.

```
{ $project : { name : 1, event : 1, group:"$event_joined.group", _id:0 } }
```